# Pandas nlargest with NaN inside my data return more than n rows of data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nan

I have `DataFrame` looks like this:

```
  Name  Score1  Score2  Score3
0    A      98      72      99
1    A      98      84      91
2    B      34      20      81
3    A      98      93      88
4    B      68      97      12
5    A     NaN      72     NaN
```

I want to `groupby` name, then take top 2 on `Score1`, if duplicate values, then look at `Score2` whichever larger. Expectation:

```
  Name  Score1  Score2  Score3
0    A      98      93      88
1    A      98      84      91
2    B      68      97      12
3    B      34      20      81
```

i tried `df.groupby("Name").apply(lambda x:x.nlargest(2, ["Score1", "Score2"])).reset_index(drop=True)`. What i get is:

```
  Name  Score1  Score2  Score3
0    A     98      93      88
1    A     98      84      91
2    A     98      72      99
3    A    NaN      72     NaN
4    B     68      97      12
5    B     34      20      81
```

I found that because of `NaN`, it returns me more than 2 rows of data for `Name A`. Is `dropna` the only way to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try fill the nan or drop them before using nlargest.

```py
cols = ["Score1", "Score2"]

df[cols] = df[cols].fillna()
#df = df.dropna(subset=columns)

out = df.groupby("Name").apply(lambda g: g.nlargest(2, cols)).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it like this:

```
out = df.sort_values(['Score1', 'Score2'], ascending=False).groupby('Name').head(2)
print(out)
```

```
  Name  Score1  Score2  Score3
3    A    98.0      93    88.0
1    A    98.0      84    91.0
4    B    68.0      97    12.0
2    B    34.0      20    81.0
```